# C++ and Visual Studio 2008, how to develop the following web extracting application? Follow-up of last general question

Tags: visual-c++, desktop

The purpose is to use C++ in a useful way.

I have just started programming and have made a few small applications in C and C#.
My understanding is that programming for web and thing related to web is nowadays a very easy task.

Please note this is for personnel learning, not for rent a coder or any money making.

An application which can run on any Windows platform even Windows 98.

The application should start automatically at a scheduled time and do the following.

1. Connect to a site which displays stock prices summary (high low current open).
2. Capture the data (excluding the other things in the site.)
3. And save it to disk (an SQL database)

Please note:-

Internet connection is assumed to be there always.

Do not want to know how to make database schema or database.

The stock exchange has no law prohibiting the use of the data provided on its site, but I do not want to mention the name in case I am wrong, but it's for personal private use only.

The data of summary of pricing is arranged in a table such that when copied pasted to MS Excel it automatically forms a table.

What guidance can you offer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to learn C++, begin with a small application. The app you propose may sound small, but for the set of technologies you want to incorporate, C++ is not very appropriate, especcially if you're a beginner.

C++ has added value mostly for high performance applications such as scientific code, DirectX games, video compression.